# How to change the xml:lang attribute value in xml?

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell, I basically use it to manipulate multiple xml files for my work assignments. I work with proprietary xml-based files, meaning they have their own extensions but are basically xml. I would be grateful if you could help me figure out how you can change the value of the 'xml:lang' attribute in the below example with a ps1 script. Let's assume I have multiple files with the *.flprj extension and they all share below contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CatapultProject Version="1" xml:lang="en-gb" />
```

What I would like to achieve is change the value of the xml:lang attribute recursively in all subfolders containing *.flprj files from 'en-gb' to let's say 'nl-nl'. I figured out how to achieve this by replacing strings, but I'd rather have replace value as the source languages might differ. I would much appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example to get you going. Might have to adjust it depending on your xml (multiple lang-values, locations ++).

1. Find all flprj-files
2. Read them and convert to XMLDocument
3. If CatapultProject.lang equals 'en-gb', modify and save

Ex:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Folder\" -Filter "*.flprj" -Recurse | Foreach-Object { 
    $xml = [xml](Get-Content $_.FullName)
    if($xml.CatapultProject.lang -eq 'en-gb') {
        $xml.CatapultProject.lang = "nl-nl"
        $xml.Save($_.FullName)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much:) Using the '-ne' operator instead of '-eq' I managed to get all langs not equal to 'nl-nl' changed to 'nl-nl', as 'en-gb' was just one of the languages. I got what I needed, so yes, problem solved, thank you once again Frode.